# which version of apollo-angular is compatible with angular 13

Tags: angular, apollo-client, angular13, apollo-angular

I am trying top upgrade angular version to 13 from 12.
I want to know which apollo-angular and apollo-client version are comptaible with angular 13.

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

import { COMMON } from '../../../helpers/constants';

context('Authorization - Breach Exporter', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.interceptGQL('swbUserProfile', 'breaches/new-breach-case/user-profile-breach-exporter.json', 200, COMMON);
        cy.visit('/breaches');
    });
    describe('Breach export', () => {
        it('should display download breaches link if user click user name button', () => {
            cy.getByDataSelector('user-name-button-group').should('be.visible');
            cy.getByDataSelector('user-name-button-group').click();
            cy.getByDataSelector('user-name-button-group').contains('Download Breaches');
            
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v3.0.1 of apollo-angular is compatible with Angular 13 (see [this](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/blob/v3.0.1/package.json))

By the time of writing `apollo-angular-link-http` has been published last time 3 years ago. Feel free to fork this repository or perhaps submit a PR.
Also you may try a `--legacy-peer-deps` option to resolve link-http incompatibility but it is hacky.